# Springboot: how can i handle a stackoverflow error cause my oneToMany mapping

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to retrieve data the will be parsed to the UI via string boot, but i keep getting a long error, which i know is due to the @oneToMany mapping:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putVal(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1012) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1535) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.getClassLoadingLock(ClassLoader.java:463) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:404) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
at org.thymeleaf.util.JavaScriptUtils.printObject(JavaScriptUtils.java:365) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.util.JavaScriptUtils.print(JavaScriptUtils.java:184) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.util.JavaScriptUtils.printKeyValue(JavaScriptUtils.java:346) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.util.JavaScriptUtils.printMap(JavaScriptUtils.java:337) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.util.JavaScriptUtils.printObject(JavaScriptUtils.java:365) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.util.JavaScriptUtils.print(JavaScriptUtils.java:184) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.util.JavaScriptUtils.printCollection(JavaScriptUtils.java:322) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.util.JavaScriptUtils.print(JavaScriptUtils.java:173) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.util.JavaScriptUtils.printKeyValue(JavaScriptUtils.java:346) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.util.JavaScriptUtils.printMap(JavaScriptUtils.java:337) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.util.JavaScriptUtils.printObject(JavaScriptUtils.java:365) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.util.JavaScriptUtils.print(JavaScriptUtils.java:184) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.util.JavaScriptUtils.printKeyValue(JavaScriptUtils.java:346) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.util.JavaScriptUtils.printMap(JavaScriptUtils.java:337) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.util.JavaScriptUtils.printObject(JavaScriptUtils.java:365) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.util.JavaScriptUtils.print(JavaScriptUtils.java:184) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.util.JavaScriptUtils.printCollection(JavaScriptUtils.java:322) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.util.JavaScriptUtils.print(JavaScriptUtils.java:173) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
```

I have two classes ClothModel and Tasks class.

```
 @Entity
public class Task extends DefaultEntity{


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "cloth_model_id")

    private ClothModel clothModel;

    private String details;

    private boolean completed;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")
    private Employee employee;


    @JsonBackReference
    public ClothModel getClothModel() {

        return clothModel;
    }

    public void setClothModel(ClothModel clothModel) {
        this.clothModel = clothModel;
    }

    public String getDetails() {
        return details;
    }

    public void setDetails(String details) {
        this.details = details;
    }

    public boolean isCompleted() {
        return completed;
    }

    public void setCompleted(boolean completed) {
        this.completed = completed;
    }

    public Employee getEmployee() {
        return employee;
    }

    public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
    }
}




 @Entity
public class ClothModel extends DefaultEntity {



    private ClothingType clothingType;

    private int quantity;

    private double amount;

    @Transient
    private String modelStructure;

    private String savedUrl;


    @Transient
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SELECT)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Task> getTasks() {

        return tasks;
    }

    public ClothModel setTasks(List<Task> tasks) {

        this.tasks = tasks;

        return this;
    }


    public ClothModel setTask(Task tasks) {

        this.tasks.add(tasks);

        return this;
    }


    public ClothingType getClothingType() {

        return clothingType;

    }

    public ClothModel setClothingType(ClothingType clothingType) {

        this.clothingType = clothingType;

        return this;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public ClothModel setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
        return this;
    }

    public double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public ClothModel setAmount(double amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
        return this;
    }

    public String getModelStructure() {
        return modelStructure;
    }

    public ClothModel setModelStructure(String modelStructure) {

        this.modelStructure = modelStructure;

        return this;
    }

    public String getSavedUrl() {
        return savedUrl;
    }

    public void setSavedUrl(String savedUrl) {
        this.savedUrl = savedUrl;
    }
}
```

My main problem is that:

1. I am able to save/update a ClothModel entity to the database via and api call, but when i want to retrieve a clothModel it crashes, I am sure as a result of the  List tasks property it has.
2. Using  @JsonManagedReference, @JsonBackReference has not been helpful, as it still gives me the error.

can someone please assist me on a way to stop this error

Comment: I do not see an @Id coulmn in the entity. What attribute are you using as JoinColumn as I cant see either employee_id or cloth_id in the entity

Comment: @TuhinKantiSharma i have a DefaultEntity.class that my entities extends which have the property of id